# Node.js Class Module System

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a module/class in node.js to measure asynchronous execution time but do not understand whats wrong with it. I created the following class "Measure.js"

```
var Measure = module.exports = function(param_timeout, param_cb) {

    this.timeout = param_timeout;
    this.cb = param_cb;
}

Measure.prototype = {
    startDate: "0",
    timeout:"0",
    cb:null,

    start : function() {
        this.startDate = new Date();
        console.log('started');
    },

    stop : function() {
        var stopDate = new Date();
        this.cb(null,(stopDate-this.startDate));
    }
}
```

I use it with the following code:

```
var Measure = require('./Measure.js');
measure1 = new Measure(100,function(err,result){console.log('result: ' + result)});
measure1.start();
//do something 
measure1.stop();
```

and it works just fine. However, if I try this:

```
var Measure = require('./Measure.js');
measure1 = new Measure(100,function(err,result){console.log('result: ' + result)});
measure1.start();
//do something 
setTimeout(measure1.stop,100);
```

it doesn't work and throws a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'cb'
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you directly call object's method, `this` inside the method referred to your object, but when you try to use it as argument, `this` will referred to global object (`global` or `window`).

In your case better to replace

```
setTimeout(measure1.stop,100);
```

with

```
setTimeout(function() { measure1.stop(); }, 100);
```

More about `this` behavior: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this

Answer (score 3):

The dreaded timeout-switch-context bug strikes again! You see what you see because `this` object in function called by setTimeout is not `measure1` - it's `global` (=`window`, when this script is executed in browser). Quoting [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_%27this%27_problem):

> Code executed by `setTimeout()` is run in a separate execution context
>   to the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the `this`
>   keyword for the called function will be set to the `window` (or `global`)
>   object, it will not be the same as the `this` value for the function
>   that called `setTimeout`.

It's quite easy to check, by the way:

```
stop: function() {
  var stopDate = new Date();
  if (! this.cb) { 
    console.log(this); 
  } // *Window*/_display...
}
```

... and to fix as well:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  measure1.stop(); 
}, 100);
```